# Calling a stateful LSTM as a functional model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a stateful LSTM defined as a Sequential model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(..., stateful=True))
...
```

Later, I use it as a Functional model:

```
input_1, input_2 = Input(...), Input(...)
output_1 = model(input_1)
output_2 = model(input_2)  # Is the state from input_1 preserved?
```

Is the state from  `input_1` preserved when we apply `model` again on `input_2`? If yes, how can I reset the model state in between the calls?

Answer (score 2):

Following **Note on using statefulness in RNNs** from this [link](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#recurrent) and [Keras implementation](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/57429d1567b94955ac95afe87792411a420ff0ba/keras/layers/recurrent.py) the answer is **yes** if:

1. The `batch_size` in both models is the same (it's important due to the way Keras computes the inner states).
2. You would first build and compile both models and then use them - for some reason Keras is resetting the inner states during the `build` of a layer (you can check it [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/57429d1567b94955ac95afe87792411a420ff0ba/keras/layers/recurrent.py) by looking for `reset_states` method).

If you want to reset states you could call `reset_states` method on each recurrent layer you want ot reset states on.

Comment: Thanks! But do you know where in the [Layer base class](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/57429d1567b94955ac95afe87792411a420ff0ba/keras/engine/topology.py) are the states saved for a stateful model called as a function?

Comment: But stateful option has a sense only for a recurrent layers. Other layers don't have a state to be remembered.

Comment: Ah right, so it wouldn't be in `Layer`. Where exactly are the states saved for a stateful model called as a function?

Comment: Every recurrent layer should have a states field. So e.g. if your first layer is recurrent then model.layers[0].states should return states of a layer given.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm hoping you can provide some insight into where the state is calculated and saved. It looks like it's done in the [RNN.call method](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/57429d1567b94955ac95afe87792411a420ff0ba/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L214). What is the context of this method? How is it called for model.predict() vs model()?

Comment: As I checked it seems that call method is in context of both of these calls.

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?

Comment: Yes, can you point me to the lines where the call method is being used?