# keras flow_from_directory over or undersample a class

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to do a binary classification problem with Keras, using the `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory` method to generate batches. However, my classes are very imbalanced, like about 8x or 9x more in one class than the other, causing the model to get stuck predicting the same output class for every example. Is there a way to set `flow_from_directory` to either oversample from my small class or undersample from my large class during each epoch? For now, I've just created multiple copies of each image in my smaller class, but I'd like to have a bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With current version of Keras - it's not possible to balance your dataset using only Keras built-in methods. The `flow_from_directory` is simply building a list of all files and their classes, shuffling it (if need) and then it's iterating over it.

But you could do a different trick - by writting your own generator which would make the balancing inside the `python`:

```
def balanced_flow_from_directory(flow_from_directory, options):
    for x, y in flow_from_directory:
         yield custom_balance(x, y, options)
```

Here `custom_balance` should be a function that given a batch `(x, y)` is balancing it and returning a balanced batch `(x', y')`. For most of the applications the size of the batch doesn't need to be the same - but there are some weird use cases (like e.g. [stateful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759332/calling-a-stateful-lstm-as-a-functional-model/41792464#41792464) RNNs) - where batch sizes should have a fixed size).

Answer (score 11):

One thing you can do is set the `class_weight` parameter when calling `model.fit()` or `model.fit_generator()`.

It also happens that you can easily compute your class_weights using `sklearn` and `numpy` libraries as follows:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
import numpy as np

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
           'balanced',
            np.unique(train_generator.classes), 
            train_generator.classes)
```

Afterwards, it becomes as simple as setting your `class_weights` equal to `class_weight` parameter:

```
model.fit_generator(..., class_weight=class_weights)
```

Comment: How can you guarantee `np.unique(train_generator.classes)` will return the classes in the proper order?

Answer (score 1):

You can also calculate the number of files in each class and normalize the class_weights

```
files_per_class = []
for folder in os.listdir(input_foldr):
    if not os.path.isfile(folder):
            files_per_class.append(len(os.listdir(input_foldr + '/' + folder)))
total_files = sum(files_per_class)
class_weights = {}
for i in xrange(len(files_per_class)):
    class_weights[i] = 1 - (float(files_per_class[i]) / total_files)
print (class_weights)
...
...
...
model.fit_generator(... ,class_weight=class_weights)
```

Comment: Hey I know this is an old answer, but I ran into this and liked this solution. There's one issue with the above: os.listdir is not guaranteed to return in alphabetical order, but flow_from_directory does; the solution I used was:
lst = os.lisdir(input_foldr);
lst.sort();
Which then sorts these weights in (hopefully) the same order as flow_from_directory.

Comment: I'm still concerned that individual batches of e.g. 32 samples will be balanced. If all the samples come from one class (likely for very imbalanced datasets) then the weights will only be pushed to classify these samples in the overweighted class direction. In the case of a batch that happens to have a rare sample, how does class_weight increase teh effect of that one sample in the batch? I suspect it is more tricky than made out.